# Excel Approaches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on assessing what a workbook does, that has numerous sheets, and a lot of formulas.

There is a "formula" that I am seeing here and there, and I am wondering if the distinction it represents is significant (or even existent).

In some cases the formula in a cell is of the type, `=P9`.  Other places it is like `=SUM(P9)` (yes, referencing just a single cell).

Then there are the regular `SUM()s`, `=SUM(P9:P12).`  But there is also, several `=P9+P10+P11+P12)` entries.

So, the question is, does the use of the `SUM()` formula for a single cell differe in performance or nuance from directly referencing the cell (`=RC`)?

Does using SUM() or not for ranges of cells differ in performance or nuance from simply referencing each of them in a =*n* 1+*n* 2+*n* 3+*n* 4 construct?

Or am I finding in this workbook the missteps of a clown?

Comment: I do not see where any topic is specified, so I am not sure how it is that what I posted is "off topic..."

Willing to comply by posting appropriately.

I thought that adding "tags" was the means for establishing the topic...

Comment: I don't see why this question is Offtopic as it is about Excel formulas and is very much on topic as per [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199823/slight-amendment-to-close-reason) latest post in meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm voting for the clown :)

If there were always `SUM` formulae even for single cells then I would suspect the formulae has been modified at some point in time from pointing at multiple cells (or multiple inputs)

But `P9+P10+P11+P12` is a blantant abuse of Excel and calls into question the model design.

Gary's answer above is correct, but the idea that a model would be deliberately designed to use a `SUM` formula to potentially point at text rather than numbers is worse again than `P9+P10+P11+P12`

Comment: Thanks Brett.  That is more or less what I thought, but I spend little time with Excel, so I was unsure.

Comment: + 1 I don't see why this question is Offtopic as it is about Excel formulas and is very much on topic as per [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199823/slight-amendment-to-close-reason) latest post in meta.

Answer (score 0):

**=P9**

will get you the value of P9.

**=SUM(P9)**

will get you zero if P8 contains text